# Android-Unity service NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, sockets, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a service from Android to send data to Unity, I've been following this [tutorial](http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/1/post/2014/02/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity.html)  to do so and works perfectly, however I need to create a socket connection to receive data from a server and then send it as a broadcast message just like the tutorial shows. The problem is that I get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when launching the app because of the socket connection. I've seen that using `AsyncTask` could be possible to solve the problem but I still don't know how to implement the service and send a broadcast message in this way.

**This is the service code:**

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();


// It's the code we want our Handler to execute to send data
private Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
        // the specific method which will be executed by the handler
        public void run() {

                Socket socket = null;

                try{

                    socket = new Socket("x.x.x.x", 1337);

                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    String line ="";

                    line = input.readLine();                    

                    numIntent++;

                    // sendIntent is the object that will be broadcast outside our app
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

                    // We add flags for example to work from background                    
                    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND|Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES  );

                    // SetAction uses a string which is an important name as it identifies the sender of the itent and that we will give to the receiver to know what to listen.
                    // By convention, it's suggested to use the current package name
                    sendIntent.setAction("com.test.service.IntentToUnity");

                    // Here we fill the Intent with our data, here just a string with an incremented number in it.
                    //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Intent "+numIntent);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, line);
                    // And here it goes ! our message is send to any other app that want to listen to it.
                    sendBroadcast(sendIntent);

                    // In our case we run this method each second with postDelayed
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }
};

// When service is started
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        // We first start the Handler
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
        handler.postDelayed(sendData, 1000);
}
```

I'm not sure if this a simple question as these are my first steps with android services and unity but I haven't found a solution to it.
Any recommendation is well appreciated or if you know another way to send data to unity from an android service where a socket connection is made would be great!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from `Service` to `IntentService`, should fix the issue. IntentService runs on a separate thread, while `Service` runs on the UI Thread

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still having the same error with the IntentService change: `E/AndroidRuntime(15694): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. To call the service I'm doing it `this.startService(new Intent(this, LeapService.class));` on the `onCreate` function only. Any idea why?

Comment: remove the Handler and try it again

Comment: but how do I execute the Runnable object?

Comment: now I get `E/AndroidRuntime(16680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test.leapservice.LeapService@41ef0dd8 with Intent { cmp=com.test.leapservice/.LeapService }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` do you think the socket connection and sendbroadcast call its ok?

Comment: did you switch from `Service` to `IntentService` ?

Comment: yes, and just added the constructor with no parameters

Comment: Ok, it work now! I removed `onStart()` (seems that is deprecated) and used `onHandleIntent()` instead to call `sendData.run` I'm just wondering why the Handler doesn't work? Thanks for your help!